# Codeigniter redirect does not working right

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've already tried the other codeigniter redirect not working topics, but they have different issues than mine.

[image: It throws this kind of error.]

This is the one where I put my redirect.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class SampleView extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {

    $data['title'] = 'Home';

    $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/index');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');

}

public function update() {

    $data = array(
        'item_id' => $this->input->post('i_id', true),
        'item_name' => $this->input->post('i_name', true),
        'item_price' => $this->input->post('i_price', true),
        'item_description' => $this->input->post('i_description', true),
    );

    $this->sampleviewmodel->update($data);
    redirect('sampleview/items');
}
}
```

This is the form that will link to update function.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=$this->config->base_url();?>sampleview/update">
```

This is my **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/w31_ton';
```

And this is my **htaccess**.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /w31_ton

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**PS. It all works fine, my only problem is that it won't redirect to the page I want.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load URL helper file before calling `redirect()` function for the redirect to work. Inside update function, add -  `$this->load->helper('url');` . That should fix that.

Comment: This actually solve the issue on my redirect. Kudos.